# iPhone SDK image

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, virtual-machines, iphone

I am hoping to do some iPhone development, but don't want to switch my base os to Snow Leopard.

Does anyone know the most economical, flexible and successful way to do this?

I am thinking: purchase Snow Leopard, install on empty VMWare image.

Comment: You can perfectly do iPhone development on Mac OS X Leopard.

Answer (score 3):

For clarification, only Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard **Server** and Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard **Server** are *only* allowed to be virtualized on Apple hardware. (per the EULA)

VMWare Fusion 2 and 3 both have native support for Snow Leopard Server - just insert the DVD, and start up VMWare Fusion's wizard to create a new virtual machine with Snow Leopard.

Snow Leopard Server is available for $500 USD. The iPhone SDK will run on Mac OS X 10.5.8 if you are running Leopard.